# Transformation of Chern-Simons type action under large $SO(4)$ gauge transformation

Tags: gauge-theory, dirac-matrices, chirality, chern-simons-theory

For the Chern-Simons action

$$S = \kappa \epsilon^{\mu\nu\delta}tr(A_\mu\partial_\nu A_\delta + \frac{2}{3}A_\mu A_\nu A_\delta)$$

under a large gauge transformation

$$A_\mu \rightarrow g^{-1}A_\mu g + g^{-1}\partial_\mu g$$

the change in the action receives a contribution

$$-\frac{\kappa}{3}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\delta}tr(g^{-1}\partial_\mu g g^{-1}\partial_\nu g g^{-1}\partial_\delta g).$$

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902115 (by Dunne) argues that this is related to the winding number density of the group element g

$$w = \frac{1}{24 \pi^2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\delta}tr(g^{-1}\partial_\mu g g^{-1}\partial_\nu g g^{-1}\partial_\delta g) $$

the integral of which (with appropriate boundary condition) is an integer.

[Normalization of the Chern-Simons level in $SO(N)$ gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27287) argues that this integral is instead a half integer for $SO(3)$.

I have two questions:

1. Is it also a half integer for $SO(4)$? How to see this?
2. I wish to evaluate
   $$\int d^3 x \frac{1}{24 \pi^2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\delta}tr(g^{-1}\partial_\mu g g^{-1}\partial_\nu g g^{-1}\partial_\delta g \gamma^5) $$
   for $SO(4)$. Notice the additional $\gamma^5$ in the expression -- which is the 4$\times$4 Dirac $\gamma^5$ matrix. Is there a way to argue its value from that of the usual winding number for $SO(4)$?